# What Should I Do With My Old Drawings?

Tags: halal-haram, art

Even after hearing the ruling, I went with the opinion for a while that it was okay to draw people as long as you didn’t make their whole bodies, or as long as it wasn’t your intention.

However, now I realize that that is wrong, and I desperately need guidance on how exactly I should dispose of the pictures I have made, as I do not wish to be a part of those who will be punished.

I have already seen advice on what to do to ask for forgiveness, but I am asking for how I should dispose of the pictures. It would also be appreciated if I can know what I should do to increase my chances of being forgiven.

Answer (score 0):

**First question: Are your drawings haram?**

I have recently studied many online fatwas on this subject.
Fatwas are not unanimous on what is allowed.
As I do not know, what parts of the people you have drawn, I cannot decide whether it is permissible according to all interpretations

Most strict interpretations say you must not draw [portraits](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/darululoomtt/52333) and whole bodies, maybe the [outline](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/135047). Drawings of parts of the body for medical or scientific purposes are [allowed](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/40054/using-drawings-and-pictures-to-learn-medicine).

There are also less strict interpretations who do not see a mere drawing as an animate picture, see [here](https://islamqa.org/maliki/seekersguidance-maliki/85229) and [there](https://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/ViewFatwa.aspx?ID=5987&text=drawing).

[Shia Islam](https://www.sistani.org/english/qa/01282/) does not prohibit drawings of humans at all (except drawings showing nudity or are haram for an other reason).

**If they are haram (according to whose point you trust): What should you do with them?**

You can throw them away.

**What should you do to be forgiven?**

You did not commit a sin that can't be forgiven.

You repent and ask Allah for forgiveness. It is said that we should do that by the time of your fajr prayer. You can say

> My Lord! Indeed I have faith. So forgive me my sins, and save me from
> the punishment of the Fire.

Because it is written:

> And those who when they commit an indecency or do injustice to their
> souls remember Allah and ask forgiveness for their faults; and who
> forgives the faults but Allah. And (who) do not knowingly persist in
> what they have done. (As for) these their reward is forgiveness from
> their Lord, and gardens beneath which rivers flow, to abide in them,
> and excellent is the reward of the labourers (3:135-136)

Allah is the most merciful.